# Prove ${m\choose n} \leq \frac{m^m n^{-n}}{(m-n)^{m-n}}$ using complex analysis

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I already know, using the Cauchy Integral Formula, that
$${ \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int _{\gamma}{ \frac{z^m}{(z-1)^{n+1}}\,dz} = {m \choose n}}$$ 
where $\gamma$ is a positively oriented circular path around $z=1$ with arbitrary radius. I am supposed to use this result. So I know that the left hand side equals 
$\frac{1}{n!}f^{(n)}(1)$ with $f(z)=z^m$. Should I somehow find  a bound on the $n$-th order derivative of $f$? Maybe with Cauchy estimates? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $\gamma$ can be any contour as long as it contains the pole $1$. Try the circle centered at $0$ and radius $m/n$ (where, $m > n$).

Comment: Then I obtain a bound on the modulus of the integrand of $\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)^m \left(\frac{n}{m-n}\right)^{n+1}$. So using a ML-inequality doesn't help then.

Comment: I see. Okay try using $\binom{m}{n} = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma} \frac{(1+z)^m}{z^{n+1}}\,dz$ for $\gamma = \{|z| = r\}$. Then triangle inequality (ML ineq) gives $\binom{m}{n} \le \frac{(1+r)^m}{r^{n}}$. Then note that $r = \frac{n}{m-n}$ is a critical point of $f(r) = \frac{(1+r)^m}{r^{n}}$....